# How do I update or create user profiles in SharePoint 2013 On-Prem using Managed CSOM

Tags: development, csom, sharepoint-on-prem

I have a requirement to create and update user profiles in our on-premises SharePoint environment using managed CSOM (C#) from within an SSIS package.

I'm able to retrieve user profiles without issues; however, I'm having trouble updating existing profile properties and creating new profiles.

Can this be done at all using Managed CSOM?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

User Profiles cannot be created or Updated using CSOM as of now. You can update user profile properties using CSOM in SPO but not in On-Prem.

[image]

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163800.aspx)

You can only do it with Server Side Object Model. See this post on [Creating User Profiles using SSOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163142.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your response. In that case what would be the alternative when using the SSOM is not an option?